# Majority of feature maps of CNN are black

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, cnn, convolution

Assuming we have a following CNN : Conv->MaxPool->Conv->Maxpool->Linear.

What does it mean - intuitively - if the majority of the feature maps of the first convolutional layer are black i.e. have no activation?. Does that mean the corresponding filters which created the feature maps are useless i.e. extract no relevant information, so that we would achieve the same performance by removing them?

Comment: That means they map to zero, check your initialization.

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! Would you be able to add more details about: layer sizes, activation functions, training data, and any hyperparameters you've set?